# Replacing only the nth instance of character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way a can replace the 1st instance of a character in a string with something eg.

```
^1402 WSN NIAMLAB^teertS htimS 005
```

to be

```
&1402 WSN NIAMLAB^teertS htimS 005
```

keeping the second ^ in place

Comment: You have asked many questions, people have answered you. Please contribute by telling us which answer works for you. For each of your past questions, tick one of the answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To replace the first instance of a character I would recommend the use of the `STUFF` and `CHARINDEX` functions.  `STUFF` inserts a string into another string. It deletes a specified length of characters in the first string at the start position and then inserts the second string into the first string at the start position.

```
DECLARE @str varchar(100) = '^1402 WSN NIAMLAB^teertS htimS 005'
SELECT STUFF(@str, CHARINDEX('^', @str), 1, '&')
```

Note that you could also use `STUFF` in a query as follows:

```
SELECT STUFF(<yourcolumn>, CHARINDEX('^', <yourcolumn>), 1, '&')
FROM <yourtable>
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the example in your question is how to replace only the 1st occurance of a char, your title indicates you want to replace the nth occurance which is a bit trickier.

I wrote a function awhile back to find the nth occurance of a character in a string. You could use than to construct a string with SUBSTRING.

```
if exists (
    select 1
    from dbo.sysobjects 
    where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[CHARINDEX3]') 
        and xtype in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF'))
begin
    drop function [dbo].[CHARINDEX3]
end

GO

/*
Example:
SELECT dbo.CHARINDEX3('a', 'abb abb a', 3)
SELECT dbo.CHARINDEX3('b', 'abb abb a', 5)
SELECT dbo.CHARINDEX3('a', 'abbabba', 3)
SELECT dbo.CHARINDEX3('b', 'abbabba', 5)
If @occurance > the max Occurrence, the function will return the max Occurrence
*/

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CHARINDEX3
(
    @TargetStr char(1), 
    @SearchedStr varchar(max), 
    @Occurrence int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret INT

    ; WITH
      -- Tally table Gen            Tally Rows:     X2                X3
      t1 AS (SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT 1 N),    -- 4            ,    8
      t2 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t1 x, t1 y),            -- 16            ,    64
      t3 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t2 x, t2 y),            -- 256            ,    4096
      t4 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t3 x, t3 y),            -- 65536        ,    16,777,216
      t5 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t4 x, t4 y),            -- 4,294,967,296,    A lot
      Numbers AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) Num
                  FROM t3 x, t3 y)
    SELECT TOP 1 @ret = Num 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Ident = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N.Num), N.Num 
        FROM Numbers N
        WHERE N.Num <= DATALENGTH(@SearchedStr)
            AND SUBSTRING(@SearchedStr, N.Num, DATALENGTH(@TargetStr)) = @TargetStr
    ) R 
    WHERE Ident <= @Occurrence
    ORDER BY Ident DESC

    RETURN @ret
END

GO
```

Using that function you can get the location of the nth occurance and simply pull all the chars before and after the occurance, replacing the specific value.

```
--Actual Code
DECLARE @loc INT
DECLARE @MyStr VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @replacement CHAR(1)

SET @MySTr = '^1402 WSN NIAMLAB^teertS htimS 005'
SET @replacement = '$'
SELECT @loc = dbo.CHARINDEX3('^',@MyStr, 2)

SELECT SUBSTRING(@myStr, 1, @loc-1) + @replacement + SUBSTRING(@MyStr, @loc + 1, LEN(@MyStr)-@loc)
```

This example replaces just the 2nd `^` with `$`

Answer (score 0):

Untested code:

```
SELECT STUFF('^1402 WSN NIAMLAB^teertS htimS 005', charindex('^', '^1402 WSN NIAMLAB^teertS htimS 005'), 1, '&');
GO
```

However, if the character doesn't exist, you would want to surround that with an if/then on `charindex('^', '^1402 WSN NIAMLAB^teertS htimS 005') != 0`