# Easiest way to remove the first instance of two different words in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a column that has some `<p>` tags like:

```
<p>test  test 2</p>    <p>this is a test 2</p>    <p>this is a test 3</p>
```

What is the best way to always remove the first `<p>` with corresponding `</p>`.

So that the result becomes:

```
test test 2 <p> this is a test 2 </p> <p> this is a test 3</p>
```

It should work for any case even `<p>1</p>` it should result in just `1`.

I tried using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` but I end up with a lot of hardcoded #'s :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ugly, but it should work.  The code basically finds the first instance of `</p>` and gets everything to the right of it.  It also gets everything to the left of it, replacing the first `<p>` it finds.

```
DECLARE @x nvarchar(100)
SET @x = '<p>test test 1</p> <p>this is a test 2</p> <p>this is a test 3</p>'

SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(@x, charindex('</p>', @x) - 1), '<p>', '') +  
    RIGHT(@x, len(@x) - charindex('</p>', @x) - 3)

SET @x = '<p>1</p>'

SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(@x, charindex('</p>', @x) - 1), '<p>', '') +  
    RIGHT(@x, len(@x) - charindex('</p>', @x) - 3)
```

This should return:

```
test test 1 <p>this is a test 2</p> <p>this is a test 3</p>
```

And

```
1
```

**EDIT**:

Based on [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845961/sql-server-2008-replacing-only-the-nth-instance-of-character), how about:

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(@x, CHARINDEX('</p>', @x), 4, ''), 
    CHARINDEX('<p>', @x), 3, '')
```

Comment: Yes these were similiar solutions I had, but is there anything cleaner just to replace the first occurrence of `<p>` and `</p>` ?